# jQuery, how to make the code always resume?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After one click, if I click for different element the code do not resuming back. And then the code working like one click only, how I can make the code always resume? if I click for the different element after one click, I wanna the code resume for two clicks again

```
var isTouchDevice = (function () {
    return "ontouchstart" in document.documentElement;
}());
if (isTouchDevice) {
    $("ul#primary-menu2 > li.menu-item-has-children2 > a").one("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: I feel like you need more details in this question-- it isn't clear what you're asking.  What I can tell you is that the [`.one`](https://api.jquery.com/one/) method you are using is specifically designed to only execute the handler a single time and then unbind, as opposed to [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/), which remains bound in perpetuity.  Also, what is the purpose of the IIFE in assigning a value to `isTouchDevice`?

Comment: I have 3 buttons with the code. When I click the first button one time, then if I go to click the second button, and then go back to the first button click, the first button works only 1 click. Not two clicks like should be. Idk about IIFE, you mean the code has bug? It is not my code, so I can't tell you about IIFE anything.

Comment: are you trying to store a value in a variable and when click another button stores again a value to a variable? is that what your trying to do?, because if you want to resume a code by clicking, it can be possible but only by using a confirmation functions like confirm, or alert etc.

Comment: [IIFE is an immediately-invoked function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).  It is design pattern, not a bug, but I don't understand its purpose in the above code.

Comment: @JenuelGanawed Yes, button stores again value to a variable. It is what I trying to do.

Comment: @PaulGalaxys, I'm not sure if this would help but try using this one. check this example https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt

Answer (score 1):

Your code is using [`.one`](https://api.jquery.com/one/), which by design will only execute its handler a single time and then unbinds.  If you swap it for [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) it will remain bound and continue to execute for subsequent clicks.  See the example below:

```js
$("ul#primary-menu2 > li.menu-item-has-children2 > a").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="primary-menu2">
  <li class="menu-item-has-children2"><a>Click me</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children2"><a>Click me</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children2"><a>Click me</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

***OPTION 1*** 
This might not be a good way, but this might help. try something like this. I hope this helps :) Try using a prompt() to store data in a varialbe.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Prompt</h2>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var txt;
  var person = prompt("Please enter your name:", "Harry Potter");
  var age = prompt("What is your age:");
  var address = prompt("what is your address:");
  if (person == null || person == "") {
    txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
  } else {
    txt = "Hello " + person + "! your age is "+age+", your address is "+address;
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

***OPTION 2***
try by storing a value in an element and hide them.

```js
function clickFirst(){
  let value = "this is value 1";
  $('#firstvalue').val(value);
}

function clickSecond(){
  let value = "this is value 2";
  $('#secondvalue').val(value);
}

function go(){
  if($('#firstvalue').val() == '' || $('#secondvalue').val() == ''){
    alert("Click First and Second First");
    return false;
  }
  let write = $('#firstvalue').val() + ' and ' + $('#secondvalue').val();
  alert(write);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="firstvalue" value="" hidden/>
<input id="secondvalue" value="" hidden/>


<button onclick="clickFirst()">First Click</button>
<button onclick="clickSecond()">Second Click</button>
<button onclick="go()">Go</button>

<div id="show">
  
</div>
```